# how to pass xml file as parameter in soapui

Tags: soapui

I need to pass and xml file(complete xml content) as parameter in SoapUI but i could not found how to send it. I tried this

```
<arg0>
<!--Optional:-->
<parameter1>&lt;test>like this&lt;/test></parameter1>
<!--Optional:-->
<parameter2><![CDATA[<test>or like this</test>]]></parameter2>
```

But I don't want like this. I want to send/upload complete xml file from SoapUI. How to attach xml file as input parameter in SoapUI? or any other solution for this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [link](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/adding-headers-and-attachments.html).

> soapUI supports the following technologies for working with files and
>   attachments:
>
> - MTOM - a technology for optimized transfer of binary data in SOAP Messages
> - SOAP with Attachments in accordance with Attachments Profile - a MIME-based attachment mechanism for the SOAP/HTTP binding
> - Inline files for binary content - soapUI specific functionality for simplifying handling of binary message content